# Infinite Load Data MySQL

Tags: mysql

My LOAD DATA (from a csv file) doesn't stop where it should.

```
 LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'E:/Applications/MySQL/MySQL Server 8.0/Data/arpege_database/Book1.csv'
    INTO TABLE bdd_project
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';'
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
    IGNORE 1 LINES
(unité,GEH,GU,Usine,...);

**Query OK, 1048425 rows affected, 65535 warnings (36.33 sec)
Records: 1048425  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 1048251**

Exemple of unexpected lines added : 
                                                |                | NULL         |                     0000 |                      |                           |                      |                      |                      |                             |              |                         |
                                                      |                | NULL         |                     0000 |                      |                           |                      |                      |
```

I normally except about two hundred lines . The last line of my csv is like the others (the csv come from excel : CSV UFT8).

As you probably all notice I'm a beginner in mysql. I couldn't find a solution by myself  (saw many tutorials using the same code as me without any problems).

Thanks for helping me !

Comment: I don't think the problem is with load data statement, more like your file has extra data in there.

Comment: What does your .csv file look like if you view it with Excel, OpenOffice Callc, or a text editor? How many lines? Are they well-formed?

Comment: @O.Jones You are right when I open it with the notepad after an empty part I found many more lines. Thanks you (and sorry it was really simple to solve)

Comment: @Shadow You are right when I open it with the notepad after an empty part I found many more lines. Thanks you (and sorry it was really simple to solve)